# Settings and game mechanics for Sherlock Holmes–inspired theme

Tags: game-recommendation, investigation

We tried to organize an investigation-based campaign, and we used the D&D engine. Unfortunately, this engine is not suited for investigation. The Call of Cthulhu engine is better, but it's deeply oriented towards the Lovecraftian setting.

For a more Victorian setting, with investigation as a central theme, what would you suggest?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

GUMSHOE. This game is probably the best investigative game out there. It's resource based mechanics are perfect for most any type of investigative game. I've used it for Sherlock Holmes-style great detectives to House style games. Trail of Cthulhu would work well, just ignore all the mythos material. Which doesn't seem to be a problem if you thought of Call.

A second option, a little more difficult but better rooted in the era may be Castle Falkenstein, but I have no idea if it is still available in any way.

Comment: Castle Falkenstein is available at http://rpg.drivethrustuff.com/product_info.php?products_id=2370&it=1 in PDF.

Answer (score 9):

The Gumshoe System from Pelgrane Press. http://www.pelgranepress.com/gumshoe/index.html

It's light, flexible and targeted directly at investigation/mystery scenarios.

Comment: This. GUMSHOE is the only system I know of which was explicitly created from the ground up with the explicit intention of being used for investigative games. It's also an excellent system on its own merits, with a lot of excellent design ideas that are really quite cutting-edge.

Answer (score 4):

I know the question already has an accepted answer (out of several great ones) and that you found the Call of Cthulhu too Lovecraft-oriented for "Sherlockian" adventuring, yet I think **Cthulhu by Gaslight** (or Call of Cthulhu: Gaslight) deserves at least passing mention. This old sourcebook contains a wealth of *relatively* brief, to the point, concise information about Holmes' London, from locations through customs to character archetypes, castes and "classes." I'd highly recommend it to all those who need a thorough yet far from encyclopedic introduction to the world of Sherlock Holmes (and just leave the tentacled stuff out. :))

Comment: +1 because a lot of people would not realise this. Bill Barton, who wrote the 1st edition, is an avid Holmes enthusiast, and it shows! The next edition (3rd) is going to have less Holmes material, and more historical stuff, so arguably if you want it for this purpose, you should look for the earlier editions.

Comment: wow, there *was* a second edition? :-o i've missed that, thanks for the info!

Comment: Yes, but there wasn't a lot of difference between the 1st and 2nd editions, other than putting it all into one book, rather than having a boxed set. See discussion [here](http://www.yog-sothoth.com/threads/243-Cthulhu-Gaslight-1st-Edition-versus-2nd-Edition) for details.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know Gumshoe so I can't comment. But I suggest [Forgotten Futures](http://www.forgottenfutures.com/) for a lot of background and nice ideas, especially if you want to stray a bit from pure Sherlockian canon and want to add some steampunk and paranormal elements (e.g. Karnacki).

Forgotten Futures is the labor of love of a very talented UK author and has been "in print" (i.e. available in electronic format, starting with floppies sent by snail mail) for decades, so you can expect a lot of stuff, and quite affordable (most if not all can be downloaded for free, I think).

On the other hand, if you want to stick to Sherlockiana, see if you can find a copy of [Sherlock Holmes Consulting Detective](http://www.boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/2511/sherlock-holmes-consulting-detective) on eBay. It will give plenty if ideas (and nice props) for adventures.

Comment: Forgotten Future books are a great purchase. The depth of love for the setting and the insight it gives makes them a very useful addition to one's shelf.

Answer (score 1):

I would, as always, recommend the excellent GURPS Mysteries [<sup>RPGGeek</sup>](http://rpggeek.com/rpgitem/53194/gurps-mysteries) book, by Lisa J. Steele. Typical of GURPS sourcebooks, it's got a lot of information on the genre in question. However, I found it particularly useful for its discussion of how mysteries in RPGs must differ from literary mysteries. Have fun!

Answer (score 0):

If you like CoC's mechanics, just use Chaosium's [Basic Role Playing](http://catalog.chaosium.com/index.php?cPath=37). It's the same engine, made generic.

Or, simpler, just ignore the SAN rules and the mythos based skills, and use CoC. (Which is, in essence, exactly the same thing as using BRP.)

And the issue of failed spot can be handled by a borrowed bit of advice out of Burning Wheel:
A failed roll is not a failed task, but a task that succeeds after some difficulty.